# Сделал шифрование для некоторой информации, но мне кажется что этот код можно написать намного лучше

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, шифрование, aes

Есть вот такой код

```
package com.cargodelivery.cargodelivery.services.cryptography;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

@Service
public class EncryptDataAESImpl implements EncryptDataAES {
    private SecretKey secretKey;
    private final int T_LEN = 128;
    private final int KEY_SIZE = 128;
    private Cipher encryptCipher;

    @Override
    public String encryptDataValue(String value) {
        secretKey = init();
        return encrypt(value);
    }

    @Override
    public SecretKey init() {
        try {
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keyGenerator.init(KEY_SIZE);
            return keyGenerator.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String encrypt(String value) {
        byte[] messageBytes = value.getBytes();
        try {
            encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] encryptBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(messageBytes);
            return encode(encryptBytes);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException |
                 IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка во время шифрования!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String value) {
        byte[] messageBytes = decode(value);
        try {
            Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(T_LEN, decode(value.substring(0, encryptCipher.getBlockSize())));
            decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, spec);
            byte[] decryptBytes = decryptCipher.doFinal(messageBytes);
            return new String(decryptBytes);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException |
                 BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка во время шифрования!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String encode(byte[] data) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] decode(String data) {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
    }
}
```

Как его можно улучшить? В плане читаемости и подобного.
Вроде работает, но кажется что можно сделать получше

Comment: Это похоже не вопрос, а просьба о code review.  У вас есть какие-то конкретные проблемы с представленным кодом или вас просто "терзают смутные сомнения"?

Comment: Скорее терзают смутные сомнения что это будет корректно работать

Comment: Где взял этот код?

Comment: Сам написал, просто видео смотрел разные и примерно написал